# How to make global parameter in bison c++

Tags: c++, bison, lex

I'm trying to make a map that can be used in flex and bison together.

This is what I tried putting in bison:

```
%{
    #include<string>
    #include<string.h>
    #include<map>
    using namespace std;
    map<string,int> vars;
%}
```

and my flex includes this:

```
%{
#include "ex3.tab.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
%}
```

I get the error " ‘vars’ was not declared in this scope " when I try to access from flex to vars.

I know it's just a simple syntax question but I couldn't find an example for it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because the variable declaration for `vars` is not in the Bison-generated header file. You need t add an `extern` declaration yourself in your Flex file.